# ng-model for input type 'number' not working angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I have integrated requirejs with angular app.. before intregrating requirejs,

```
<input type="number" value="{{cart.quantity}}" ng-model="cart.quantity" />
```

was showing the value in input box.
But after integrating with requirejs, input box with type="number" not showing me the value..
input box with type="text" is working.

How can I show value with type="number" ?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you setting both `value` and `ng-model` ? ngModel will place  cart.quantity into your input automatically!

Answer (score 29):

I just ran into this same issue and managed to solve it. In my case, the model is being obtained via a RESTful `$resource` and the value for the amount is being provided as a string to the field, which in turn wipes out the value. In order to address this, I ended up doing the following in my controller:

```
$scope.cart = Cart.get(id: $routeParams.id, function(cart){
    cart.quantity = parseFloat(cart.quantity, 10);
});
```

which turns the value into a float, prior to updating the view. One gotcha I ran into is that my first attempt was setting `$scope.cart.quantity = parseFloat($scope.cart.quantity, 10)` immediately after the `get`. This was not working since the value was overwritten when the async call to `get` completed.

```
$scope.cart = Cart.get(id: $routeParams.id);
$scope.cart.quantity = parseFloat($scope.cart.quantity, 10); // This won't work
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didnt get "Expense.get(id: $routeParams.id, (e) ->
    e.amount = parseFloat(e.amount, 10)
)"... can you pls elaborate ? or can you generate fiddle ?

Comment: It's coffeescript. I've updated the answer with Javascript, maybe this makes it clearer.

Comment: I just ran into the exact same issue binding to a '$resource` response.  It's unfortunate we have to parse out the number explicitly when binding but I suppose it's a small price to pay for the validation we get for free in the view.  In any event, thanks a lot for posting as this quickly helped me move past this.

Comment: +1 In my case, I've made the server-side provide an integer instead of a string. [My model lives on the server.](http://wekeroad.com/2013/04/25/models-and-services-in-angular)

Comment: most ridiculous bug ever

Comment: `parseInt(<int>)` and `parseFloat(<float>)` did the trick on init, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Your binded value is a `string` not a `number`.

First of all, check that your server is sending a `number`. If you are using PHP, you might want to use:

```
json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

You might also turn your `string` into `int` or `float` with Javascript on the client side:

```
var data = ['1.9', '3']; //these won't be binded to the numbers-only input
data[0] = parseFloat(data[0]); //this will
data[1] = parseInt(data[1]);
```

It's not a bug as that the `numbers` input only accepts valid numbers (hopefully).

---

**Note:**

I also tried to bind an `ng-value` with an integer filter but it wont't work. Maybe because the `ng-model` is the one that's binded when both are found (yup, they have the same priority level).

Answer (score 6):

I solve this problem using a custom directive:

```
angular.module('directives').directive('input', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, $el, attrs, ngModel) {
      if ($el.get(0).type === 'number') {
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
          return value.toString();
        });

        ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
          return parseFloat(value, 10);
        });
      }
    }
  }
})
```

This way you do not need to change any HTTP response when the data is being obtained via a restfull resource.

Restrict this directive if necessary :)

Answer (score 5):

value is overridden by ng-model.
Remove your value property, and your ng-model will fill the input with the cart quantity.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (with an input type="range" actually) and here is my solution, using a custom directive:

```
app.directive('ngFloat', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, $el, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
            return parseFloat(value, 10);
        });

        ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
            return value.toString();
        });
    }
  };
});
```

As I restricted the directive to the "ngFloat" attribute, it is need to tag the input like this:

```
<input ng-float type=.........
```

I hope this can help future visitors.

Comment: I changed `return value.toString();` to `return (value || $el.attr('min')).toString();`.. worked nicely +1

Answer (score 1):

I added a name attribute to the input and it started working

Comment: Surprisingly but it worked for me. I don't understand, why. Thanks.

Comment: I can only speculate that it is related to ngForm since the ngModelController won't be available as a property of the form without a name? not seeing anything in the code (v1.5) to confirm that though.

Answer (score 1):

If **cart.quantity** data type is not `Number`, it won't work.

Your need to

```
$scope.cart.quantity = parseFloat($scope.cart.quantity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-model in this case cart.quantity has to be a number and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link, which helped me. It creates a string-to-number directive, which you can attach to the number inputs in a similar fashion, that Ruy Diaz showed: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/numfmt

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same problem and tried to find a solution all the was complex for a newbie 
then I came across a solution at 
the old version of angular at
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D

according to which ng-model accepts a string 
the workaround is that we define a

> **min**

and

> **max**

value while using input type=" number"

It worked for me and I hope that it work for others too

Answer (score 0):

Strange, in my case, removing `min` and `max` attributes from the `input type="number"` worked for me. I mean the `ng-model` worked!!

Seems completely opposite to what arpit kumar posted above.

> AngularJS version: 1.6.1

Answer (score 0):

```
angular
  .module('xxx')
  .directive('ngFloat', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, $el, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
          return +value
        });
      }
    };
  });
```